# Can a planet have more that one ring?

Tags: planet, planetary-ring

Here is a good example picture of what I mean:
[image]

If not, why is this so? I've heard often that in the creation of a planet more the rings have formed, they are most likely just all over the place before they settle to the formation that we know, so why not come to a stable position in such a way. Note that the picture is only an example, rings that horizontal to each other are included too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can have more than one ring. [Saturn](http://www.universetoday.com/38097/how-many-rings-does-saturn-have/) is an example of a planet with multiple rings on the same axis separated by divisions (gaps between each ring).

About rings that are not on the same axis (similar to your example picture) is addressed in [this previous question](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/16536/could-a-cross-ringed-planet-exist?rq=1).

Comment: Oh ok that pretty much much answers my question. Thx!